# Split() em número inteiro com Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Valor = 19.90;

MyArray = valor.split(".");
```

o código trava , variavel inteira, porem se,

```
Valor = "19.90";

MyArray = valor.split(".");

alert(MyArray[0]) = 19;
alert(MyArray[1]) = 90;
```

Gostaria de saber como usar o split em variável int , obrigado.

De acordo com soluções, dos amigos já reputados abaixo, Edito minha pergunta para a seguinte forma.

Não , no caso acima, tenho a função,

```
function splitNum (34.50 * 2){
var s = n.toFixed(2).split('.');
var n1 = parseInt(s[0], 10); // 19
var n2 = parseInt(s[1], 10); // 10
return n1+"."+n2;
}
```

irá me retornar 
   69.0

Porém preciso que retorne 69.00 , como seria possível ? obrigado.

Resolvido, obrigado tenham uma ótima tarde.

```
function splitNum (34.50 * 2){
var s = n.toFixed(2).split('.');
var n1 = parseInt(s[0], 10); // 19
var n2 = parseInt(s[1], 10); // 10
return s[0]"."s[1];
}
```

Comment: 1: Javascript não  trabalha com "váriavel int" - 2: você pode criar seu próprio método `.split()` igualzinho ao original facilmente, veja na minha resposta como.

Comment: tenta algo assim: `Valor = 19.90;MyArray = (valor).toString().split(".");`

Comment: [Problema XY...](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/499/215) Se tudo o que você queria era formatar um número com duas casas decimais, bastava fazer `Valor.toFixed(2)`. Não precisava separar e depois juntar de novo... :)

Comment: rsrsr , eu ja usei v.toFixed(2); é que uso outras funções alem dessa, rsrsr, obrigado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `split` se aplica apenas a strings, não a tipos numéricos. Se você tem um número com 2 casas decimais (ou só se interessa pelas 2 primeiras casas decimais) você pode transformá-lo numa sting usando `toFixed`.

```
Valor = 19.90;
Valor.toFixed(2); // "19.90"

var valor2 = 1/3;
valor2.toFixed(2); // "0.33"

0.123456789.toFixed(5); // "0.12345"
```

A partir daí você pode aplicar o `split`. Lembrando que, se quiser converter de volta para inteiro*, é importante especificar a base:

```
var s = Valor.toFixed(2).split('.');
parseInt(s[0], 10); // 19
parseInt(s[1], 10); // 10

// O que acontece se você omitir a base?
var s = 0.01.toFixed(3).split('.'); // ["0", "010"]
parseInt(s[1]); // 8! (começou com zero, então ele interpreta como octal)
```

*Lembrando: **se quiser!** Se o que você quer é uma string mesmo, não converta de volta usando `parseInt`, somente use os valores `s[0]` e `s[1]` como achar melhor.

Comment: Melhor resposta. +1 pelo uso do metodo `.toFixed()`

Comment: Com a sua solução, se decimal retornar 0 , ele fica com apenas 1 número, eu preciso que fique com 2 números, ex:
Se 0 for igual 00 , teria como ?

Comment: @WilsonLavrador Desculpe, não entendi. Você fala da parte inteira ou da parte fracionária? Pelo que testei, a parte fracionária está correta, você quer fazer um *padding* na parte inteira?

Comment: Não , no caso acima, tenho a função, 

function splitNum (34.50 * 2){
var s = n.toFixed(2).split('.');
var n1 = parseInt(s[0], 10); // 19
var n2 = parseInt(s[1], 10); // 10
return n1+"."+n2;
}

Irá me retornar 69.0 , eu preciso que retorne 69.00

Comment: @WilsonLavrador Sugiro editar sua pergunta em vez de responder nos comentários. Tem mais espaço pra se explicar, e outras pessoas podem ver também.

Comment: @WilsonLavrador minha resposta atende à seu pedido da necessidade das casas decimais

Comment: @WilsonLavrador Entendi agora. Veja minha resposta atualizada.

Answer (score 4):

Não é preciso converter para string se o valor é numérico.

```
valor = 19.90;
aValores = [parseInt(valor),Math.ceil((valor  % Math.floor(valor)) * 100)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta você converter para `string` antes de usar o `split`.

Existem várias formas de converter um número para string, como por exemplo:

```
var n = 10.01;
var s = n.toString();
var a = s.split('.');
```

Aliás, você usa o termo *int* e *inteiro* para se referir a um número que não é inteiro. Esses termos se usam apenas para números inteiros (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 1000) e não para números racionais (e.g. 19.90).

**EDIT** Esta parte da resposta está errada, leia os comentários para entender.

<s>Você ainda deve querer transformar os números, depois do split, de volta em tipo numérico:</s>

```
var n1 = parseInt(a[0]);
var n2 = a.length > 1 ? parseInt(a[1]) : 0;
```

**A solução no final, ficaria assim**

```
function SplitNum(n)
{
    var s = n.toString();
    var a = s.split('.');
    var n1 = parseInt(a[0]);
    var n2 = a.length > 1 ? parseInt(a[1]) : 0;
    return [n1, n2];
}
```

A forma correta de transformar em números de volta, seria manter o que vem depois do separador decimal, depois de separador decimal:

```
var n1 = parseInt(a[0]);
var n2 = a.length > 1 ? parseFloat('0.'+a[1]) : 0;
```

Comment: não funciona corretamente: SplitNum(19.90) -> [19, 9]. O correto seria [19, 90].

Comment: Pensei que quisesse em forma de número, os dígitos `0` após a vírgula à direita, são implícitos em uma variável numérica.

Comment: Se você quiser definir a quantidade de casas decimais, então terá de trabalhar com strings mesmo. Veja [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10088/1925) do @mgibsonbr.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo +1 Isso está correto! Havia sugerido o `toFixed` na minha resposta como meio de contornar isso, mas de fato semanticamente `0.9` é o mesmo que `0.90`. Só faz diferença de você está guardando o segundo valor como "centavos" (por exemplo).

Comment: @MiguelAngelo @mgibsonbr está certo que o 19.90 -> 19.9, ok. Mas me refiro a corretude do programa. Ele pode não infrigir nenhuma regra matemático-lógica, mas mesmo estar errado quanto ao seu objetivo. E no caso, o resultado `90` seria interpretado erroneamente como `9`.

Comment: no caso, `SplitNum(19.90)[1] == SplitNumNum(19.09)[1] // true`, o que é completamente errado. outro exemplo: `SplitNum(19.91)[1] - SplitNum(19.90)[1] // 82!!`

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo Custou pra cair a ficha, mas você tem razão! Se alguém fizer `SplitNum(19.90)` e `SplitNum(19.09)` os resultados serão idênticos. P.S. Já ia comentar isso, mas você foi mais rápido rsrs

Comment: @mgibsonbr: verdade! Então a parte final da minha resposta está errada. Vou colocar um `<s>` nesta parte.

Comment: Refiz a parte final de uma forma que pelo menos não é incorreta como estava antes.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Se for seguir por esse caminho, use `parseFloat`. `parseInt` num número começado com `"0."` vai sempre ser zero.

Comment: @mgibsonbr: Exatamente... corrigido! =D

Answer (score 1):

Conforme explicado na MDN, o [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/EXSLT/str/split) serve para separar strings, e o que você está tentando fazer é separar um integer. O que você pode fazer é converter o integer para string:

```
var n =  123456789;
var digits = (""+n).split("");
```

Observe que isso irá lhe retornar um array de string, e não um integer.

Comment: Não é indicado [usar o w3schools como referência](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 1):

### Solução

Você precisa primeiro transformar o int/double em string por exemplo:

```
Valor = 19.90;

MyArray = String(Valor).split(".");

alert(MyArray[0]) // 19

alert(MyArray[1]) // 9 que no decimal é a mesma coisa que 90
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar algo do tipo:

```
var Valor = 19.9;

var Dados = $.map( Valor.toString().split("."), function(v){
    return parseInt(v); 
});
```

jQuery.map() - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Answer (score 1):

## Respondendo a sua pergunta **"Split em número inteiro com javascript"**:

Não é possivel. **Até porque Javascript não trabalha com números Inteiros(Integer), ele trabalha apenas com Number(número flutuante)**.

Porém vejo que você quer um método que realize isto para você sem você precisa utilizar linhas de código, pois é o objetivo do `.split()`, então vou te disponibilizar uma função atribuindo ela a `Number.prototype` para que você possa usar da mesma forma que o `.split()`:

```
Number.prototype.split = function(){
  var a = this.toString().split(".");
  return [parseInt(a[0]),(a[1].length > 1) ? parseInt(a[1]) : (parseInt(a[1])*10)];
} 
var Valor = 19.90;
Valor.split(); //retorna um array [ 19, 90 ]

var Valor = 19.95;
Valor.split(); //retorna um array [ 19, 95 ]

var Valor = 19.957;
Valor.split(); //retorna um array [ 19, 957 ]
```

Note que ele ignora o zero no final pois é um Number e falando em números `19.90` é a mesma coisa que `19.9`, por isso eu fiz uma verificação se o tamanho do número for maior que 1 ele multiplica por 10 assim sempre tendo o seu "zero" que você quer.

Comment: Sua verificação pelo `length` realmente atende ao caso do OP. Não é um código genérico (nenhuma das respostas é - inclusive a minha) porque sem o uso de `toFixed` alguns resultados vão ser incorretos (ex.: `19.090`). Mas nesse caso particular está OK